# Where can I ask questions regarding Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

We are currently working on new [keyboard layouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardfaq) for Indian languages. I would like to know on which relevant Q&A site I can ask questions about this so that it makes sense for the experts to find them and help us regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange makes a point of not running "forums" (because the discussion that forums are all about is the last thing any SE site wants), but the Q&A site you want is almost certainly [Super User](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), which is about computer hardware and software usage. Asking for instruction on how to work with Microsoft's tools for Windows customization should be undeniably on-topic there.

Comment: I meant Q&A site sorry not forum.